# Convert array to json

Tags: java, json

I have a multidimensional array which has integer and string values. I want to convert the array in json format and send it back to an ajax function. I am trying to print the array contents to check but i am not able to do so.

```
Os[] o1 = new os[];
o1[0].os_name = "xyz";
o1[0].os_id = 1;
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(o1);

for (int i = 0; i < jsArray.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = rec.getInt("os_id");
    String loc = rec.getString("os_name");
    System.out.println(id+loc);
}
```

i have a os class:

```
public class Os {

    int os_id;
    String os_name;

}
```

I am getting an error:

> JSONObject["os_id"] not found.

Comment: Maybe declaring a size when making the array will help, like:
`Os[] o1 = new Os[1];`

Comment: Your first line is broken. Os[] o1 = new os[]; The second 'os' isn't referring to an object and the array isn't being declared with a size.

Comment: `o1[0].os_name = "xyz";` Shouldn't even work because 1) Your array does not have a size. And 2) There are no objects in the array

Comment: I have declared the array with a size and also done Os[] o1 = new Os[]; Still it doesnt work.

Comment: Please update your question with the new code.

Comment: Show us your *actual* code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to **initialize the Array** and **the object** you are using.
Second, you need to **provide assessors** ( gettters) for the Os object properties for the Json API to work

**Your main issue concern the lack of getters in your bean. To fix the issue, change the OS class like this:**

```
public class Os {

    int os_id;
    String os_name;

    public int getOs_id() {
        return os_id;
    }

    public String getOs_name() {
        return os_name;
    }

}
```

And then your corrected code will be:

```
// In Java the Arrays must have a size
Os[] o1 = new Os[1];

/* The Array contains only null values by default. You must create 
   objects and assign them to the newly created Array. 
   ( In your example, only one object is created)  */

Os anOs = new  Os();
anOs.os_name = "xyz";
anOs.os_id = 1;

// Assign the object to the Array index 0
o1[0]=anOs;

JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(o1);

for (int i = 0; i < jsArray.length(); ++i) {
  JSONObject rec = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);
  int id = rec.getInt("os_id");
  String loc = rec.getString("os_name");
  System.out.println(id+loc);
}
```

Comment: You actually only need getters for it to work

Comment: @cricket_007 the provided example was not fully functional, so I corrected  it. You're right the main issue was related to the mandatory getter/setter to be present for the Json API to work as expected.

Comment: I was only referring to the fact that the setters aren't need, just the getters. You can see my answer for reference.

Comment: You're right @cricket_007, only the getter are required for the Marshalling process. But the Unmarshalling will need the setters to work.. So I always add both. But it's neccessary only if the transformation from java to json is made both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to do this

```
Os[] osArray = new Os[1];
Os os1 = new Os();
os1.os_id = 1;
os1.os_name = "xyz";
osArray[0] = os1;

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(osArray);
```

> I am trying to print the array contents

You can do this

```
System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
```

Which will print an empty JSON object within an array.

```
[{}]
```

Therefore, your error makes sense because you have an empty object with no keys.

To fix that, update your class like so

```
public class Os {
    int os_id;
    String os_name;

    public int getOs_id() {
        return os_id;
    }

    public String getOs_name() {
        return os_name;
    }
}
```

And you will now see

```
[{"os_id":1,"os_name":"xyz"}]
```